# Django - Grouping 2 context datasets into 1 forloop

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

For each Product I need to show all it's reviews with an attached profilepicture, this requires queries into 3 models but I need a maximum of 2 for loops as when I do the Profile for loop all the images appear together as shown below. Ideally review & profile datasets are put together so only one profilepicture appears for each review.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    releasedate = models.DateField()
    description = models.TextField()
    productphoto = models.ImageField(default='products/default_product.jpg', upload_to='products')

class Review(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1, validators = [MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)])
    reviewtext = models.TextField()

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    profilephoto = models.ImageField(default='profiles/default_profile.jpg', upload_to='profiles')
```

**views.py**

```
class ProductDetailView(TemplateView):
    # template_name = 'reviewApp/test.html'
    template_name = 'reviewApp/product_detail.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        prod = self.kwargs['pk']
        context = super(ProductDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['Products'] = Product.objects.filter(id=prod)
        context['Reviews'] = Review.objects.filter(product=prod)
        profile_ids = Review.objects.filter(product=prod).values_list('profile_id', flat=True)
        context['Profiles'] = Profile.objects.filter(id__in=profile_ids)
        return context
```

**product.html**

```
        {% for prod in Products %}
            <img src="{{prod.productphoto.url}}">
            {{ prod.brand }} {{ prod.name }}
            £{{ prod.cost }}
            {{ prod.category }}
            {{ prod.releasedate }}
            {{ prod.description }}
        {% endfor %}

        {% for rev in Reviews %}
          {% for prof in Profiles %}
            <img src="{{prof.profilephoto.url }}">
          {% endfor %}
         {{ rev.rating }}
         {{ rev.author }}
         {{ rev.reviewtext }}
        {% endfor %}
```

**view**
[image: Current View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the profile picture as `rev.profile.profilephoto`

Comment: But a User can have more than 1 Review, would that still work?

Comment: Actually, foreign key should work acc to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)
try using rev.profile.profilephoto